# Написать регулярное выражение для получения целых чисел разделенных запятой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите написать регулярное выражение для нахождения целых чисел разделенных запятой.
Например, есть строка '34,3,25,b,554,232,x,buha,234a2,1.5'
Результат должен быть таким: 34,3,25,554,232.

Comment: `\d+(?=(?[,\s]|$))` - что нибудь такое

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает. Выдает лишние цифры(2,5)

Comment: `(function(input = '34,3,25,b,554,232,x,buha,234a2,1.5') { return '34,3,25,554,232' })()` :)

Comment: Вы это к чему? Речь шла о регулярке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const reg = /(?<=^|,)\d+(?=,|$)/g;
const str = `34,3,25,b,554,232,x,buha,234a2,1.5`;
console.log(str.match(reg));
/*
(?<=^|,) - позитивный просмотр назад, на начало строки или символ запятой
\d+ - одина и более цифра
(?=[,\s]|$) - позитивный просмотр вперед на конец строки или символ запятой
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает